# Replace HTML content between two tokens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have HTML content warped in between two tokens:

```
...<p>[ShowMore]This is <b>my</b> content.[/ShowMore]</p>...
```

I want to get this HTML between the two tokens and replace it with something more complex... using jQuery.
This solution will be used in CMS web site. The gole is to hide content form user and show it on click. Basically this HTML content will be replaced with a link witch will toggle (show/hide) HTML content on user click.

User can have multiple tokens on single site.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean replace `[ShowMore]This is <b>my</b> content.[/ShowMore]` by another text ?

Comment: You don't need to post an answer for asking a following question there are comments in the OP for that.

Comment: @fedesc which he needs more points for.

Comment: @JavaScript Right. Forgot the score stuff. My bad. (though it is weird that you'd be allowed to answer a question before commenting on it :D). +1 from me to help him get there.

Comment: @fedesc  yeah, I have just been can comment so my first comment to reply you :D